# UITextView - how to start text on line x

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview

I have text and a uiimageview as a subview in a uitextview. The problem is that I can't move the text down so that the image doesn't cover it up (using \n\n\n\n\n\n etc). How can I move the text down?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i realised if you use

```
[@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" stringByAppendingString:@"bla bla text content stuff"];
```

rather than

```
@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n bla bla bla text content stuff";
```

it will push the text down somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to create a `UIView` that contains your `UITextView` and `UIImageView`. Position the `UITextView` below the `UIImageView` so that you can see your text.

Don't use newlines, spaces, etc to get your text placement right. If you change the text, you may have to do it all over again. Place your views where you want them to be displayed.

Comment: The text isn't editable, and I need the text and the image to scroll together. Since the text won't change the number of line spaces will stay the same.

Comment: You could put the `UITextView` and the `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView` instead. Your original question is not quite clear as to what you want to do.